# DataSource for DataGridView is not showing the data of the table

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview, visual-studio-2017

Within Visual Studio 2017 I just created a DataGridView and linked a DataSource to it. It asked me for a connection string (which I gave). It showed the table from the database that I wanted in the DataGridView and it created automatically the correct columns within the DataGridView for me.

But for some reason when I start the application it does not show any data. I assume it connects to the database correctly otherwise it couldn't possibly know the name of my table and the columns within it. So how comes it sees my table but does not get the data?

So to test this I tried to make a simple RadDropDownList with help of the guide "[LINK](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/dropdown-listcontrol-and-checkeddropdownlist/dropdownlist/populating-with-data/data-binding)" But by following the steps for "Data binding at design time" I get the same exact result. It seems like it connects correctly but then it shows no data.

Does anyone knows why Visual Studio connects to my database with help of a DataSource but then does not gets any data from the table? Am I perhaps missing something?

Added:

- I am using Microsoft SQL Server.
- Yes, I have checked if the table contains data.

Comment: Are you using database from visual studio (.mdf extension) or something other?

Comment: I am not using the database from visual studio.

Comment: Yea but which one you are using? Firebird, Mysql, SQLite..... [list of all database servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: did you actual check that there is any data in your table ... ?

Comment: Yes, definitely. That was the first thing I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True"; // put your connection string
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors"; // change your table name
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    connection.Open();
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
    connection.Close();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; // put your gridview name
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
```

Comment: Still don't know why Visual Studio refuses to do it but I guess this works too.